# .NET MAUI Community Toolkit SpeechToText - Listening should be ended automatically when i stop speaking

Tags: speech-to-text, maui-community-toolkit

I used SpeechToText in Xamarin-Forms, and there listening ends automatically, when I stop speaking.
I need this behaviour also in .Net Maui.

SpeechToText listening from the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit starts and stops manually or after more than a minute when I stop speaking.
Is it possible to set a time span (3 Seconds) after which SpeechToText ends listening automatically?